# Store image and then later display it in ImageView on Android

Tags: java, android

Im building an application on android that displays an image stored in a specific folder on the SD card. I want my code to build the folder on the SD card then put an image file in that folder. Then after it is created I want it to pull the image out of the folder and display it in the imageview. This is what i have so far.

```
    //create the folder then add the image here
    File SDlocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File clothingdirectory = new File(SDlocation + "/images/");
    clothingdirectory.mkdirs();
    File outputFile = new File(clothingdirectory, imagename.png);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    //pull the image out of the folder here
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SDLocation + "/images/imagename.png");
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

EDIT: sorry my question is how create the file to save on the phone. I'm missing a step. I don't have an image called imagename.png. How would i create one?

EDIT2: How do i take an image from my project folder and put in in the directory i created to pull out later?

Comment: is the code you currently have not working?  what is your question??

Comment: so you simply need a source image? where do you want the image to come from? internet? the camera?

Comment: I dont really know yet. I just wanted this to work for testing purposes. could import a file i have on my computer and place it in the project then on the phone?

Comment: Yes, that would work fine.  Give it a try and report back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry i know this is trival and probably stupid but i put the image file in the "src" folder with my java files in the project. how would i import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter,

You can put the image in your `drawable/` folder then you can set the `ImageView` with `setImageDrawable(R.drawable.imagename)`.